# Can I use my Belgian student visa to study in another Schengen country?

Tags: visas

I'm a non-EU national studying in Belgium. I'm planning on doing Erasmus for one semester in Greece next year and am wondering how I will obtain a visa.

Will I need to renew my Belgian visa again, plus get a student visa for Greece, as well? Or can I just use my Belgian student visa to stay in Greece? Or should I only obtain a Greek student visa and obtain my Belgian one once I return?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi claire. This site is for short term travel, like vacations. We have another site, [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) for living and studying abroad.

Answer (score 1):

Your Belgian D visa allows you to travel in *other* Schengen states *as if* you had a C visa. You can spend no more than 90 days out of every 180 days in Schengen states other than Belgium (partial days count).

I don't know about the academic year in Greece, but doing a semester with just 90 days presence at the university sounds impractical, especially if you can't just travel home on weekends.